# Middah keneged middah vs Moddedin

Tags: talmud-gemara, mishna, chazal

I've seen two expressions used by Chazal:

Hashem judges a person מידה כנגד מידה, measure for measure, for example [Nedarim 32a](https://www.sefaria.org/Nedarim.32a.12)

במידה שאדם מודד בה מודדין לו, by the measure a person uses They use to measure him, for example [Sotah 1:7](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Sotah.1.7)

I'm wondering if they're the same thing or is there a nuanced difference between them.

Comment: Never thought about it before, but initial reaction: MKM says that Hashem treats the person as per a reflection the person's behavior. MSMBMK say that Hashem treats the person the way he treats others. One difference is that MKM would include acts that don't harm or aid others. But more fundamentally, if more subtle, is that MKM assesses the middah in terms of the person themself, MSMBMK assesses in terms of its impact on others.

Comment: Looked at Sotah 8b, with the discussion of a person still getting whatever punishment a duly constituted beis din would have given him. I don't think my intuition holds.